# I want to get back button on left side of screen but I am unable to get it

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

```
file:///Users/anuragpanchal/Desktop/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20-%20iPhone%208%20Plus%20-%202018-10-11%20at%2014.18.24.png
```

my back button code called on view will appear func

```
//MARK: Navigation button
func backNavigationButton()  {
    let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(actionBackButton)) //
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button1

}

@objc func actionBackButton()  {
    // PopToHome()
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: where s the image

Comment: You should use ```self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [button1]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier versions of iOS use this code:

```
let leftBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: leftImage, style: .done, target: target, action: leftImageSelector)
```

for iOS 11 or above you need to add a spacer as apple changed the layout of the buttons:

```
let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        spacer.width = 5
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [spacer, leftBarItem]
```